# AWS Lambda, how to work with an expensive to construct never changing data-structure(graph)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-lambda

This is a theoretical Question. I know that i could very easily solve the stated example problem
by using some AWS GraphDatabase. I really need to let the lambda function itself to work on a bigger datastructe that is held in memory, not outsource the graph calculations or something. the Graph is just used as an example.

## The Setting:

Let's say i want to use AWS Lambda for one of my projects.
This project provides an API to search for the shortest path in a never changing graph from Vertex A to Vertex B.
Since those requests are stateless it would be perfect for something like AWS Lambda.

## The usage pattern:

This service is not used that often. Lets say like 10 times a day. But when someone
uses it, they will probably use it several times in a short period of time.

## The problem:

The Graph to work on is static, it doesn't change EVER. But it is quite big, and if
constructed from some XML-like Data it takes a few seconds. In the program, the graph consists of
a few thousand instances of a vertex class, and every vertex has a set of adjacent vertices. (undirected graph)

## The question:

How would i implement this with AWS lambda? (Example code will be java, but since this is theoretical and about aws and not java, it shouldn't matter)

- Of course i could just construct this graph from XML every time the service is requested.
  But that would take several seconds each time, to construct the never changing object structure,
  which is not suitable.
- I could persist the graph structure to ephemeral memory (/tmp) so it could get reused on subsequent
  requests as long as they happen within the 4:30Minute(lets call those 4:30min a SESSION) window that aws keeps the lambda instance environments alive.
  But loading it as a serialized version would probably also take some time.

I want to kind of persist the memory structure itself for subsequent requests during the same "session".
Reconstructing the Graph for every "session" would not be a problem if it can be used for subsequent requests within that window.

How would you solve this problem to work on a never changing structure that takes time to construct?

Or maybe i'm missing something completely?

EDIT:
Okay, i found out that you could put the construction of the graph into the initialization and store it in a variable. That solves the Question of how to reuse the graph for subsequent requests to the same container.

But the bigger questions still remains, is it possible to reuse NEVER changing (aka statless) datastructure that lives in memory?

I'm not sure this question is suitable for stackoverflow since strictly speaking, it is not about programming. But it definitely is not about servers (serverfault) either.

Comment: Regarding your statement "I know that i could very easily solve the stated example problem by using some AWS GraphDatabase". That will not be an easy task considering that AWS does not have any graph database service.

Comment: There is something that is called "titan" or something like that, that implements a graph like database by utilizing dynamoDB. But as I said. The graph was only an example. I'm not really trying to find the shortestPath.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a static graph you can compute all the paths on beforehand and store them in an appropriate data format. Then the Lambda could use a simple lookup method to fetch the pre-calculated path. Exactly how this format looks like may vary, and depending on the size of the graph the storage methods may also vary, see examples below.

---

For file based storage you could use JSON, either as a key / value. The key contains the start and end vertices, the value is a list of intermediate vertices. If the vertices are not connected, there is no corresponding key, e.g.

```
{
  "AB": ["C", "D", "E"],
  "AC": [], // empty list indicates a direct connection
  "AD": ["C"], 
  "AD": ["C", "D"],
  "BA": ["E", "D", "C"],
  // etc
}
```

If you would like to know the path from `A` to `B` you simply generate the key `AB` and the path will be `C`, `D` and `E`.

You can also use a nested JSON format:

```
{
  "A": {
      "B": ["C", "D", "E"],
      "C": [], // empty list indicates that there is a direct connection between A and C
      "D": ["C"],
      "E": ["C", "D"]
  },
  "B": {
      "A": ["E", "D", "C"]
      // etc
  }
  // etc
}
```

Here, you find the path from `A` to `B` by looking up the value `A.B`.

---

For large graphs / data sets, [DynamoDB](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/) could be one suitable option on the AWS stack. One way of modelling it could be to use a [composite primary key](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.CoreComponents.html#HowItWorks.CoreComponents.PrimaryKey) where the start vertex could be the *primary key* and the end vertex the *sort key*. Then the path could be a list of strings with the intermediate vertices as in the file example.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately you solved the problem, that was just an example for the underlying problem "How to reuse a expensive to construct data-structure"